# Writing programs in an unsupported language

Tags: programming-practices, programming-languages, text-editor

Is it possible to write a program in a language unsupported by an editor or IDE, save it, then run it in different IDE or editor that does support the language?

Comment: Do you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: I am writing a program in Vim in an unsupported language then I want to save it and run it in Xcode or Visual Studio.

Comment: Usually yes, but ultimately it depends on the language/tool.

Comment: What do you mean by "unsupported language"?

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: @DanPichelman I mean languages that are unsupported by the editor without adding extra plugins or extensions.

Comment: Wow, someone who never experienced times when editors did not have any language support - I start feeling really old.

Comment: @DocBrown I hear you.  I wrote a lot of code using vi back in the day.

Comment: You would be missing out on the whole "integrated" part of "integrated development environment"

Comment: This is a completely valid question but my god it hurts that it is. You're lucky I don't know where you live. I want to beat you over the head with punch cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Ultimately an IDE is just a text editor so you can open text that was created in one editor in another editor.

Comment: But not all languages are text! Scratch is blocks and connections between them, traditional Smalltalk is objects in memory that are "edited" by calling methods on them telling them to edit themselves, programs for Intentional's Domain Workbench are Semantic Graphs stored in a Semantic Database, and Piet is an abstract painting. (That latter one is a joke. I mean, it is a real language, but it was created as a joke.)

Comment: Sorry for using a swear word (twice), but you can't really edit APL in a none APL editor if you want to maintain your dwindling sanity. Of course working in that language in its editor is still quite a strain on your sanity.